# Laravel app usages more than 90% CPU resources for only 100 concurrent users

Tags: linux-networking, apache2, php7

I have migrated the existing application from core php to laravel framework. But the laravel application usage more than 90% cpu for the 100 concurrent users but the same application developed in core php usages the 5% cpu load only for the same load.

Then I have created one sample 'helloworld' application in laravel for load testing and result is the same. I have tested the laravel application using load testing tool siege, hits url '`siege www.mysite.com/helloworld -c250 -t20s`' for 250 concurrent users (duration 20 sec) and still cpu load reaches more than 90% (linux centos 7.5 8 core 8 gb ram apache).

Also tested the core php file 'helloworld.php' using same load testing tool ('`siege www.mysite.com/helloworld.php -c250 -t20s`') but CPU usage not exceeded even 5%.

I am using

- the latest php version ie 7.2
- linux server centos 7.5 8 core 8 gb ram
- apache
- also tried the varnish http cache
- laravel version 5.4 (also tried the 5.6 but the result is the same)

I don't know where is the issue I have tried everything but still not resolved the issue. Is there anything missing in the configuration on the server or in the coding end. Please suggest.

Comment: Experiencing the exact same delima. Using seige with 100 concurrent users shoots cpu utilization up to 90 - 96% but ram utilization is only around 1-2GB. Did you ever discover what was causing this?

Comment: Have you discover the solution? im facing the same problem laravel consume high cpu for only 100 concurrent user..